# Rails 3: update_attributes sets column to 'nil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The problem I'm having is with the method update_attributes. The code:

n is set to an Active Record object.
`n = Notification.find(notification_id)`

Then, n is updated with the hash notification_options. 
`n.update_attributes(notification_options)`

The issue I'm having is when I 
`raise n.inspect`
It shows the two fields are set to nil. Also, in the database the two fields are empty.
Why won't it update the attributes?

Let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: could you show the `notification_options` hash? You speak about two fields, which fields??

Comment: have u set the attributes as accessible?

Comment: Excuse me, when I spoke about fields, what I meant to say was two keys have a value of nil. The two keys being origin and destination. And yes `attr_accessible :origin, dest` is included

Comment: Would be helpful if you could include your model and the exact code you're trying to use. We can't see if there's a typo. I believe 'dest' should have a colon before it for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using `attr_accessor`, and not `attr_accessible`, I would guess. Please show us your Notification model.

Answer (score 0):

So it ends up that the issue was with a line in the model for a gem that being used. It needed a specific format which was causing it to set to nil if it didn't match.